# Is Artie Ziff richer than Mr Burns?

Tags: the-simpsons

In The Simpsons, series 13, episode 10; Half-Decent Proposal, Marge is reminded of her former boyfriend Artie Ziff by a news report in which Kent Brockman says these lines:

> Gentlemen, start your envy! Men's world magazine has listed the one hundred richest men in the country, and coming in at number five is Springfield native, Artie Ziff.

Now, it makes sense that local news would mention a local person being on that list, but isn't Mr Burns an obvious omission? His main character traits are wealth and cruelty. Wouldn't he be in the top five? Is it possible he's not on the list at all?

So, is Artie richer than Monty at that point? Any tv/comic/comicon sources?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**

According to [Forbes Fictional 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbes_Fictional_15), he was [number 11](https://www.forbes.com/2002/09/13/400fictional.html) with 1B in 2002 and [number 13](https://www.forbes.com/2008/12/18/fictional-characters-wealth-oped-fictional1508-cx_de_mn_1218fictionalintro_slide_14.html) with 996M in 2008 which matches what happened in episode [The Burns and the Bees](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/The_Burns_and_the_Bees) where:

> [When billionaires learnt Mr. Burns lost 4 million dollars short of a billion dollars, he was kicked out. Billionaires threw him over to the Millionaire Camp, having only $996,036,000.](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/The_Burns_and_the_Bees)

So, although he is one of the wealthiest fictional characters, his fortune isn't enough to make him richer than Artie Ziff or one of the wealthiest persons in the real world/shows universe!

Comment: In __[The Ziff Who Came to Dinner](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ziff_Who_Came_to_Dinner)__ (Season 15) Artie is living in the Simpson's attic because he is broke. So it seems that currently he is __not richer__ than Mr. Burns.

Comment: @Oliver_C I did specify at that point in the show.

Comment: @madmada I'm so happy this information exists.

Comment: @AJFaraday - Yes, and __"The Burns and the Bees"__ is an episode from __Season 20__ (2008). The episode you talk about is from __Season 13__ (2002). Hence it would make more sense to link to the [Forbes Fictional Fifteen from 2002](https://www.forbes.com/2002/09/13/400fictional.html) instead of 2008 _(Mr. Burns net worth fluctuates, e.g. [in 2007](https://www.forbes.com/2007/12/11/forbes-fictional-rich-oped-books-cx_de_mn_fict1507_1211top_slide_7.html) he was listed with $8.4 billion)_

Comment: And in the link you posted from 2002, he's at #11with 1 B.

Comment: @madmada - Yes, so why use a number and episode from 2008 when the question is about 2002? As I pointed out, Mr. Burns net worth fluctuates, so saying he had $996m in 2008, doesn't technically answer if he was richer than Artie in 2002.

Comment: Obviously I used the information I found/knew about which was enough to give an estimation of his fortune.  Now, l'll add the 2002 link to the answer (when l'm on my pc)

Comment: You should also add a reason why you think Artie had more than $1B. Right now your answer is only saying "Burns had $1B, therefore Artie was richer".

Comment: The question already states that Artie (at the time) was the 5th richest man in the country, so it's enough to prove that Mr Burns isn't rich enough to be.

Comment: Artie is only the 5th riches within the Simpsons universe. Mr. Burns is the 11th riches of all fictional characters. If anything, this shows the Burns is richer, since Artie is not even on that list.

Comment: Only main characters (who are part of the narrative story) are included in this list. And in real world, 1B isn't enough to even make it to the top 500 in America, so, why would we assume that the show is drasticly different?

Comment: Was this before or after Mr. Burns accidentally gave his trillion-dollar bill to Fidel Castro?